# Add image id and class to Cloudinary image

Tags: html, image, api, cloudinary

I am using [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com) to do direct image uploads, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to add an 'id' or 'class' to an image. This could be done when displaying the image, or when uploading - I just need an identifier!

Can someone help point out where to do this in the documentation? I assume it is a feature since they have many advanced features. I can't use Javascript to add element identifiers since my whole application is based around this feature - those with JS would not be able to use the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the development environment you use. 
For example, in jQuery, to add class and id when creating an image tag you can simply add them as parameters:

```
$.cloudinary.image("sample.jpg", {id: "my_id", class: "my_class"})
```

Please update your question with the exact development environment you use and I will add the appropriate sample.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing. Was going crazy as I has different behavior for Chrome and IE8. I figured out how to add a class, but not yet the ID. The solution above works but only for modern browsers, for older ones (like IE8) it worked like this (using the addClass fucntion):

```
    $.cloudinary.image(your_image_id, 
    { your_html_options }).addClass('your_class'));
```

Hope this helps...